# How to show Vimeo videos in my own app

Tags: video, appcelerator, vimeo, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have an app for Android and iPhone where we want to create a page with some videos for the user to see (instructions). These videos are all on Vimeo (you can see them [here](http://www.fiskepleje.dk/Raadgivning/fangstjournal-dtu-aqua#Fangstjournal-dtu-app)).

I understand that I cannot get the url to the "real" media file - and therefore cannot use the `<VideoPlayer>` control. I have tried to set up a simple `<Webview>` to show the video in a similar fashion as on the web page I referenced above. This seems to work on Android - but for iPhone it just doesn't appear... This is a snippet of the code:

```
    <View class="formRow">
        <WebView html="<html><body><iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/151036965' width='320' height='240' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"></WebView>
    </View>
```

If I put a simple link on the same page:

```
    <View class="formRow">
        <WebView html="<a href='http://vimeo.com/151036965'>Se video</a>"></WebView>>
    </View>
```

... then I can press that link and then watch the video - so the format for playing should be Ok.

Any insights/suggestions would be appreciated :-)

/John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a little odd... When trying Shawn's suggestion I had left my own attempts in there as well - and the line I had shown in my question actually works now!

```
<View class="formRow">
    <WebView html="<html><body><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/151036965' width='320' height='240' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"></WebView>
</View>
```

I cannot explain why... However, I did add the last three attributes in my last attempt prior to asking here. I can only guess that somehow they did not take effect when I tried it. It doesn't seem to matter if I reference the video using `http` or `https`, so I have ended up using `https`.

But to sum up - the above markup seems to show the video player correctly for Android as well as iPhone :-)

/John

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<WebView url="http://player.vimeo.com/video/151036965"></WebView>
```

And see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It didn't quite do the trick for me. It showed up - but without any player controls etc. However, I found a solution - and have answered to make it available to others :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use "flutter_html" package from pub.dev for showing whole content in your app.